# Why does this function show 24?

Tags: javascript

```
const factorial = (n) => {

return innerFactorial(n, 1);

function innerFactorial (x, y) {
if (x == 1) {
  return y;
}
else {
  return innerFactorial(x-1, x * y);
}} }

factorial(4)
 /=> 24
```

I am thinking if 4 is used as n and y has to be 1, then inner factorial parameters should be 4-1, 4 times 1, and so it should be 4 times 1, then 3 times 1 then 2 times 1 then 1 times 1, and equal 10, but it equals 24 and I'm not sure why. Can someone please explain this function. This is from a book on Ecsmascript 6.

Answer (score 0):

The function you show multiplies the values,  so 4*3*2*1 = 24

Answer (score 0):

**STEP 1**

`factorial(4)` = `innerFactorial(4,1)` = `innerFactorial(4-1,4*1)` = `innerFactorial(3,4)`

**STEP 2**

`innerFactorial(3,4)` = `innerFactorial(3-1,4*3)` = `innerFactorial(2,12)`

**STEP 3**

`innerFactorial(2,12)` = `innerFactorial(2-1,12*2)` = `innerFactorial(1,24)`

**STEP 4**

`innerFactorial(1,24)` = `24`

Answer (score 0):

This is what is being returned each recursive loop:

```
return innerFactorial(4-1, 4 * 1);
...
return innerFactorial(3-1, 3 * 4);
...
return innerFactorial(2-1, 2 * 12);
...
return 24;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just walk through the loop to see what happens:

```
innerFactorial(4, 1)
```

This leads to:

```
innerFactorial(4-1, 4*1) // innerFactorial(3, 4)
```

Which leads to:

```
innerFactorial(3-1, 3*4) // innerFactorial(2, 12)
```

Then:

```
innerFactorial(2-1, 2*12) // innerFactorial(1, 24)
```

Finnaly, because `x==1`, this returns `y`, which is 24.  The function you wrote is a correct way to calculate factorials.

Answer (score 0):

```
Factorial(4)
=> innerFactorial(4, 1)
=> innerFactorial(4-1, 4 * 1);
=> innerFactorial(3, 4);
=> innerFactorial(3-1, 3 * 4);
=> innerFactorial(2, 12);
=> innerFactorial(2-1, 2 * 12);
=> innerFactorial(1, 24);
=> 24 // if the first param is 1, return 24
```